# Who is the seventh Shichibukai?

Tags: one-piece

it's a well known fact that the Shichibukai are seven. When one of them resigns (Jimbei), dies (Moria) or goes under arrest (Crocodile) he/she is replaced for another one like Blackbeard, Law and Buggy.

So after the 2 years skip the current Shichibukai are:

- Law
- Mihawk
- Flamingo
- Kuma
- Boa Hancock
- Buggy (lol)

Who is missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The missing Shichibukai is [**Edward Weevil**](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Edward_Weevil), who is introduced in [chapter 802](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Chapter_802).

> Edward Weevil, or "Whitebeard Jr." is the self-proclaimed son of Edward Newgate and one of the Shichibukai. His mother is Miss Bakkin, the self-proclaimed lover of Newgate.He was first mentioned by Commodore Brannew in a discussion of the current Shichibukai ranks to several high-ranking Marine officers, but was not explicitly named until after Donquixote Doflamingo's defeat.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

(Note this answer is now outdated.)

The anime seems to make a serious point about not revealing who the seventh one is.  I doubt it has been revealed yet in the manga.  That means the answer is we don't and can't know yet.

That being said the current "shichibukai" are:

- Law
- Mihawk
- Doflamingo
- Kuma
- Hancock
- Buggy

Blackbeard left the warlords and is now much more powerful.

Comment: I meant Mihawk, my bad. Blackbeard was the 7th, then he left

Comment: He is now Yonko... i think that trupes warlord any day.

Comment: Yes, definitely

Comment: Oh Yes ! Buggy the  " Strongest " Shichibukai . HAHA.

Comment: @Silver the irony is, he is acting as a distribution center just telling his uberpowerful subordinates where to go... Mihawk has no crew; Law's crew is detained and his particular skills aren't that useful against Buggy; Kuma is effectively walking dead and i don't think has a crew; Hancock's crew is comparatively unremarkable; we know nothing about the last guy....thanks to Luffy and his buggy balls (still more powerful than the navy cannons), he might actually be the second strongest Shichibukai in terms of overall team strength

Answer (score -1):

[image]

- law

  - mihawk
  - doflamingo
  - kuma
  - hancock
  - buggy
  - shiki the golden lion

`but since doflamingo is defeated and marines arrest him for his evil deeds and law is in alliance with the strawhats. 2 positions for warlords will be vaccant ^__^. i think that was an ressemblance to shiki :)

Comment: Try to add reference to back up your answer.

Comment: shiki the golden lion isn't shicibukai, in the picture I think it's [Edward Weevil](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Edward_Weevil) just like Dario's answer

Comment: Wrong answer! No references! Just assumptions...